# How to sum rows by ID and value column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a table:

```
ID     type       value
a1    income       100
a1    income       70
bb    spending     30
bb    spending     20
```

How to sum columns with same ID by value as one row? Se desired results is:

```
ID     type       value
a1    income       170
bb    spending     50
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with adding `as_index=False` in your `groupby.agg`:

```
>>> df1.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg({'type':'first','value':'sum'})

   ID      type  value
0  a1    income    170
1  bb  spending     50
```

Comment: thanks, and what does ```'type':'first``` does? can I past there two values?

Comment: ```'first'``` returns the first value of each group.  So if 'type' == 'other' in row 1, the above outcome for a1 would show 'other', as it's the first value of the type column, when we group by ID (and ID == 'a1'). Same process is repeated for bb, and other ID's.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_table.groupby(['ID', 'type']).sum()
```

should do the trick

Comment: yeah, but all other columns disappear, only type and value remains. and why its square brackets? it says TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I've edited the answer, it was a mistake on my part. Now it should include all 3 of the columns